Do the validator params become part of the validator code, and are therefore included in the script address?
Re https://plutus.cardano.intersectmbo.org/docs/auction-smart-contract/on-chain-code

Note that AuctionParams is not an argument of the compiled validator. AuctionParams contains contract properties that don't change, so it is simply built into the validator by partial application.

This means that if I create multiple auctions with different parameters, each will have a different script address, correct?

Yes, that's right. The parameter values you provide gets set in the validator resulting in different script CBORs for different values. Script address is derived from the hash of a script's CBOR.
Different Script CBOR -> Different Script Hash -> Different Script Address.
